# How to combine two byte arrays

Tags: java

I have two byte arrays and I am wondering how I would go about adding one to the other or combining them to form a new byte array.

Comment: If you add them then how would you deal with overflow?

Comment: Where are you doing any addition?

Comment: Bytes can be 0-255 so the sum of two bytes can overflow the range.  (E.g. 255 + 1 = 256, overflow!)

Comment: @maerics:Bytes are signed (-128 to 127).  They overflow back into the negative range.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot that everything is signed in Java.  But I suppose overflow is still overflow, right?

Comment: Using `ByteArrayOutputStream` is a nice way. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9133993/1617737

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You're just trying to concatenate the two `byte` arrays?

```
byte[] one = getBytesForOne();
byte[] two = getBytesForTwo();
byte[] combined = new byte[one.length + two.length];

for (int i = 0; i < combined.length; ++i)
{
    combined[i] = i < one.length ? one[i] : two[i - one.length];
}
```

Or you could use `System.arraycopy`:

```
byte[] one = getBytesForOne();
byte[] two = getBytesForTwo();
byte[] combined = new byte[one.length + two.length];

System.arraycopy(one,0,combined,0         ,one.length);
System.arraycopy(two,0,combined,one.length,two.length);
```

Or you could just use a `List` to do the work:

```
byte[] one = getBytesForOne();
byte[] two = getBytesForTwo();

List<Byte> list = new ArrayList<Byte>(Arrays.<Byte>asList(one));
list.addAll(Arrays.<Byte>asList(two));

byte[] combined = list.toArray(new byte[list.size()]);
```

Or you could simply use `ByteBuffer` with the advantage of adding many arrays.

```
byte[] allByteArray = new byte[one.length + two.length + three.length];

ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(allByteArray);
buff.put(one);
buff.put(two);
buff.put(three);

byte[] combined = buff.array();
```

Comment: Or you could use System.arraycopy()

Comment: Good call. I'd never seen `System.arraycopy();`

Comment: And personally, I always use System.arraycopy, often with wrapper methods for the common case... actually I've long since written an `ArrayUtil.resize` method.

Comment: Arrays.asList() does not work with an array of primitive types. How can this *actually* be done?

Comment: You cannot use `list.toArray(new byte[list.size()])` with primitive types. Instead it should be `Byte[] combined = list.toArray(new Byte[list.size()])`

Comment: `ByteBuffer#put(byte[])` will always use offset 0. Meaning that doing `buff.put(one);` followed by `buff.put(two);` will not append but overwrite. You would need to do `buff.put(one.length, two);`

Answer (score 36):

You can do this by using Apace common lang package (`org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils` class ). You need to do the following

```
byte[] concatBytes = ArrayUtils.addAll(one,two);
```

Comment: Is it fast. I need a really fast method. Without overhead of looping.

Comment: Your fear of overheads make me think you are troubled by your UI freezing whenever you perform this loop. Perhaps you should consider an `AsyncTask` (android), which is the only way of stopping a loop from interrupting your UI thread.

Answer (score 8):

I think it is best approach,

```
public static byte[] addAll(final byte[] array1, byte[] array2) {
    byte[] joinedArray = Arrays.copyOf(array1, array1.length + array2.length);
    System.arraycopy(array2, 0, joinedArray, array1.length, array2.length);
    return joinedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The **simplest** method (inline, assuming `a` and `b` are two given arrays):

```
byte[] c = (new String(a, cch) + new String(b, cch)).getBytes(cch);
```

This, of course, works with more than two summands and uses a concatenation charset, defined somewhere in your code:

```
static final java.nio.charset.Charset cch = java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1;
```

Or, in more simple form, without this charset:

```
byte[] c = (new String(a, "l1") + new String(b, "l1")).getBytes("l1");
```

But you need to suppress `UnsupportedEncodingException` which is unlikely to be thrown.

---

The **fastest** method:

```
public static byte[] concat(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
    int lenA = a.length;
    int lenB = b.length;
    byte[] c = Arrays.copyOf(a, lenA + lenB);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, lenA, lenB);
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String temp = passwordSalt;
byte[] byteSalt = temp.getBytes();
int start = 32;
for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i ++)
{
    byteData[start + i] = byteSalt[i];
}
```

The problem with your code here is that the variable i that is being used to index the arrays is going past both the byteSalt array and the byteData array.  So, Make sure that byteData is dimensioned to be at least the maximum length of the passwordSalt string plus 32.  What will correct it is replacing the following line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i ++)
```

with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < byteSalt.length; i ++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `byteData` array is biger than `32 + byteSalt.length()`...you're going to it's length, not `byteSalt.length`. You're trying to copy from beyond the array end.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this code which works quite well just do appendData and either pass a single byte with an array, or two arrays to combine them :

```
protected byte[] appendData(byte firstObject,byte[] secondObject){
    byte[] byteArray= {firstObject};
    return appendData(byteArray,secondObject);
}

protected byte[] appendData(byte[] firstObject,byte secondByte){
    byte[] byteArray= {secondByte};
    return appendData(firstObject,byteArray);
}

protected byte[] appendData(byte[] firstObject,byte[] secondObject){
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );
    try {
        if (firstObject!=null && firstObject.length!=0)
            outputStream.write(firstObject);
        if (secondObject!=null && secondObject.length!=0)   
            outputStream.write(secondObject);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: cool comment 7 years later @Farid, thanks for your input and for reviving the thread.