# Merging 2 audio files sequentially in android?

Tags: java, android

how can merge two audio files to a single file in android platform.
that is if i have two audio files namely A and B.Please give me the code to create a new audio file C that is appended by B after A.
Is there any need to convert the audio files to byte/short array ??...

i did like this but it  plays 1st file only.

```
            File firstFile=new File("/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/Dictation/Audio/Dict136.3gp");

            File secondFile=new File("/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/Dictation/Audio/Dict139.3gp");

            System.out.println("1 file:::::"+firstFile+"\n 2nd file::"+secondFile);


           FileInputStream fistream1;
        try {
            fistream1 = new FileInputStream(firstFile);
            FileInputStream fistream2 = new FileInputStream(secondFile);//second source file



            SequenceInputStream sistream = new SequenceInputStream(fistream1, fistream2);
            FileOutputStream fostream = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/Dictation/Audio/merged.3gp");//destinationfile

            int temp;

            while( ( temp = sistream.read() ) != -1)
            {
                System.out.print( (char) temp ); // to print at DOS prompt
                fostream.write(temp);   // to write to file
            }



            filePath="/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/Dictation/Audio/merged.3gp";
            playAudio(filePath);


            fostream.close();
            fistream1.close();
            fistream2.close();
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

To combine audio files that are in an 3gp or mp4 container you should be able to use https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser
Check out the samples:
https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/AppendExample.java

get the mp4parser jar (via maventral) and do this:

```
        File firstFile=new File("/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/Dictation/Audio/Dict136.3gp");
        File secondFile=new File("/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/Dictation/Audio/Dict139.3gp");

        Movie movieA = MovieCreator.build(firstFile);
        Movie movieB = MovieCreator.build(secondFile);
        final Movie finalMovie = new Movie();

        List<Track> audioTracks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Movie movie : new Movie[] { movieA, movieB}) {
            for (Track track : movie.getTracks()) {
                if (track.getHandler().equals("soun")) {
                    audioTracks.add(track);
                }
            }
        }
        finalMovie.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks.toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));

        final Container container = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(finalMovie);
        File mergedFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/Dictation/Audio/merged.3gp");
        final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mergedFile);
        FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(mergedFile, "rw").getChannel();
        container.writeContainer(fc);
        fc.close();
```

Comment: The code example you have posted head few problems but following the example from the library (link above) worked straight away.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `File Input/output Stream`  for this. To read any file in byte arrays use

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[FILE_SIZE_HERE];
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
int bytesRead = 0;
bytesRead = fs.read(buffer, 0, FILE_SIZE_HERE);
```

Here the `buffer` contain you file's byte array. In this way you can get the byte array of both the file. now in 2nd step when you have taken the byte array of bot file you need to copy both of byte array into one single array and then you can write this (3rd new array) to a new file using this

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(tempFile, true);
fout.write(data);
fout.close();
```

Where `data` is the new 3rd array you will get after merging both arrays

**EDIT:** [See this how to combine two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683486/how-to-combine-two-byte-arrays)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You can't just combine audio files and have them playback correctly. The above solution won't work.