# How to merge 2 binarybyte array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 byte array like this:

```
byte a[i]=1;
byte b[i]=0;
```

I want to merge it so that the output result becomes "10". I try to use arraycopy and make new output

```
byte[] output=a.length+b.length;
```

but it still doesn't work like my expectation. Anybody knows how to solve it?

Comment: Already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683486/how-to-combine-two-byte-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
     byte[] first = {1,2,4,56,6};
     byte[] second = {4,5,7,9,2};
     byte[] merged = new byte[first.length+second.length];

     System.arraycopy(first,0,merged,0,first.length);
     System.arraycopy(second,0,merged,first.length,second.length);
for(int i=0; i<merged.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println(merged[i]);
}
```

Comment: thank you, your example works!

Comment: user3698011 didn't get your point

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
byte[] first = getFirstBytes();
byte[] second = getSecondBytes();

List<Byte> listOfBytes = new ArrayList<Byte>(Arrays.<Byte>asList(first));
listOfBytes.addAll(Arrays.<Byte>asList(second));

byte[] combinedByte = listOfBytes.toArray(new byte[listOfBytes.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
byte a[i] = 1;
byte b[i] = 0;

byte[] output = new byte[a.length + b.length];

for(int i = 0 ; i < output.length ; ++i)
{
    if(i < a.length) output[i] = a[i];
    else output[i] = b[i - a.length];
}
```