# Cannot create an array of byte arrays in groovy

Tags: groovy, arrays

I'm getting an error when I try to create an array of byte arrays in groovy.  My code is:

```
def patch0 = [0, 2, 4, 8, 16] as byte[];
def patch1 = [0, 3, 6, 12, 24] as byte[];

def patches = [patch0, patch1] as byte[];
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[B@7630e551' with class '[B' to class 'java.lang.Number'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is that when you cast the array to a byte[] in the third line, Groovy is trying to cast each array to a byte. If you change that cast to a two-dimensional byte array the error goes away.

```
def patch0 = [0, 2, 4, 8, 16] as byte[]
def patch1 = [0, 3, 6, 12, 24] as byte[]

def patches = [patch0, patch1] as byte[][]
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is, that `[patch0, patch1]` is an **array** of `byte[]` arrays. It's not an array concatenation. Its `[[0, 2, 4, 8, 16], [0, 3, 6, 12, 24]]` which cannot be cast to `byte[]`

You could use `flatten()` method like

```
def p = [patch0, patch1].flatten() as byte[]
```

Or do smth like

```
((patch0 as List) + (patch1 as List) ) as byte[]
```

Or you can ommit a cast

```
def patch0 = [0, 2, 4, 8, 16] // will be Collection instance
def patch1 = [0, 3, 6, 12, 24]
(patch0 + patch1) as byte[] // You can plus collections, and then cast.
```

Versions above is Groovyer, but may be not as optimal.

Maybe faster solution will be smth from, [How can I concatenate two arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java) but most of all solutions there are verbose, Java-way, or use external libraries like **ApacheCommon**

Or look a t specific byte array Java concatenation. [Easy way to concatenate two byte arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513152/easy-way-to-concatenate-two-byte-arrays)